# How can I set up a covid test for re-entry into the USA from Italy?

Tags: covid-19, italy, california

### Context

I will be flying LAX -> FRA -> VCE at the end of this coming week, and then back again a few weeks later.
My understanding from talking with another traveler is that I need to have a covid test, taken with 48 hours of travel, in order to expect a smooth trip from LAX to VCE.
However, I also understand that I need a covid test to re-enter the USA.
United airlines recommends using [eMed](https://www.emed.com/); the idea is that you order the test kit before leaving the USA and then use it within three days of the return back to the USA.
However, apparently eMed won't ship to my address in California.

### Question

How have others successfully traveled to and from Italy from California while meeting covid testing requirements?

Comment: There is [covid testing available at Venice airport](https://www.veneziaairport.it/en/info-and-assistance/swab-test-covid-19.html); consult with your airline and the US authorities to see which of the tests they offer will be appropriate for your use case so that you can plan accordingly. There is probably also additional testing available in the city itself; I'm sure someone at your hotel would have ideas, as this is a common question nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Having completed the trip, I can now offer my personal experience:

For the USA->Italy trip, I had my vaccine card and no test.

For the Italy->USA trip, our host suggested that try the Venice train station. We went to the train station, but the line was so long that the workers there advised us that they would probably run out of tests for the day before serving everyone. I found a private clinic about fifteen minutes walk away and just went over there to see if I could get tested. I was then able to schedule a test for a few hours later. I returned later, got tested, and paid in cash. My companion then did the same.

One very strange thing was that the only person who checked our tests was the ticket agent in the airport. Nobody else, including anyone in the USA, checked the test information.

This was July 2021.